# Citation for trade paperback edition in APA 7

Tags: citation-style

I've been looking at the online guidance from APA (and others) for how to handle editions of the text other than the first. In particular, using the guidance here: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references

> 1. Whole Authored Book
>    ...
>
> - Use the copyright date shown on the book’s copyright page as the year of publication in the reference, even if the copyright date is different than the release date.
> - Include any edition information in parentheses after the title, without italics.

and

> 3. Republished Book, with Editor
>    ...
>
> - Provide the year of the republication in the main date element of the reference. Provide the year of original publication at the end of the reference in parentheses after the words “Original work published.”
> - Both publication years appear in the in-text citation, separated with a slash, with the earlier year first.

My question is whether a paperback printing should follow the first form or the second form, or some combination of the two.

Relevant text on the book's title page:

> Title of Book
>
> Firstname Author
>
> Publishing House Paperbacks
> New York

Relevant text on the book's copyright page:

> Publishing House Paperbacks
> A Division of Publishing House, Inc.
>
> Copyright (c) 2006 by Firstname Author
>
> First Publishing House trade paperback edition September 2007

Would the proper citation in APA 7 be:

Author, F. (2006). *Title of Book* (First Publishing House trade paperback ed.). Publishing House Paperbacks.

or:

Author, F. (2007). *Title of Book*. Publishing House Paperbacks. (Original work published 2006)

or some other combination such as:

Author, F. (2007). *Title of Book* (First Publishing House trade paperback ed.). Publishing House Paperbacks.